# Move a domain and its users from one Google Apps account to another

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, google-apps-email

I've two Google Apps accounts which look like this:

**Google Apps Account A:**

```
  sam@alpha.com  
 info@alpha.com  
 test@alpha.com  
  news@beta.com (primary domain)  
   you@beta.com (primary domain)
```

**Google Apps Account B:**

```
john@xray.com (primary domain)
```

I'd like to move all the `alpha.com` users to Google Apps Account B so the setup would now look like this:

**Google Apps Account A:**

```
news@beta.com (primary domain)
 you@beta.com (primary domain)
```

**Google Apps Account B:**

```
 sam@alpha.com
info@alpha.com
test@alpha.com
 john@xray.com (primary domain)
```

Any ideas on the best way to do this?

Essentially these accounts are only being used for email (I'm not using the Drive, Calendar or other services) so if there's a way of easily migrating just the emails and the domain users that would work.

---

**UPDATE - 23 Sept 17**
As of Nov 16 Backupify's Migrator app has closed down, so I'm now looking for an alternative workflow to migrate the data / email accounts.

Comment: it's not clear what domains are the primary domain in Account A and B. Can you clarify what domains are primary? Primary domains cannot be removed without deleting the entire Google Apps instance which adds significant complication to the process.

Comment: @JayLee - Good point, please see updated question

Answer (score 1):

Migrator for Google Apps may just solve your problem. However after the first free migration, it costs $15/migration.

https://www.migrationapp.com/

Migrator's overview and FAQ can be found at:

https://migrationapp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us

Comment: as of Nov last year i believe Backupify closed down their migration service do you know if there is an alternative workflow ?